# Configure and save application logs for azure cloud classic service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I am using azure cloud classic service. I need the application logs of azure cloud classic service for analyzing the issues. Is there a way to save the application logs of azure cloud classic service to storage account and view the logs or any other way to see the application logs of azure cloud classic service

In the configuration of azure cloud classic service, I have added a key "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" and its value contains the connection string of storage account[image: Configuration]

In the storage account I see containers (wad-crashdumps, wad-iis-logfiles)

[image: Containers]

Also I see below tables

[image: tables]

But none of these blob containers and tables contain application logs.

Could you please help me get the application logs for cloud classic service

Comment: what is the visual studio version you are using? what is the framework and version of your application?

Comment: Visual studio 2022 and .NET Framework 4.8. The cloud classic service is already deployed. We have been using since long time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're halfway through using the Azure Diagnostics extension:

1. Set up your cloud service with permission to write to a storage account. (Looks like this is already done per your notes)
2. Hook up your cloud service a trace listener that works with Azure Diagnostics and start tracing messages. See [Trace the flow of a Cloud Services (classic) application with Azure Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics-trace-flow) for more context on the configuration you need to change.
3. Ensure that your application is set up to publish the logs to the storage account and view the logs that exist there. See [Store and view Diagnostic data in Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/diagnostics-extension-to-storage) for more context on this configuration and some tools that you might find useful for baseline review of logs.

It's difficult to provide a more precise answer than these doc links given the lack of further specificity in the question, but reading these docs should provide a good starting point for you.